# Compare between multiple columns and remove similar instances

Tags: python, pandas, count

I want to count number of instances where **label remains the same and features** **change**(F1,F2,F3,F4..and so on), and instances where **label changes and features remain same**.

And also remove **one row out of two**, where nothing changes, neither the `label` nor the `features`.

I haven't tackled such a scenario before, so I am not sure what would be the most efficient way to go about this. I have been looking into stack overflow questions and searching online, any suggestions or ideas with this, would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df
   api_spec_id commit_date        label  F1  F2  F3  F4  F5
0            1  2019-01-01        major   1   3   4   7   0
1            1  2019-04-05        patch   1   3   4   7   0
2            1  2019-10-09            -   4   4   2   6   9
3            2  2020-03-01  major.minor   1   9   4   5   5
4            2  2020-03-05            -   3   6   2   1   8
5            2  2021-04-01            -   3   6   2   1   8
```

```
groups = (
   df.assign(label=df['label'].replace('-', float('nan')))
     .groupby('api_spec_id', sort=False)
)

_label = groups['label'].ffill().rename('_label')
subset = df.columns.difference(['label', 'commit_date']).union(['_label'])
```

```
>>> df.join(_label).drop_duplicates(subset=subset)
   api_spec_id commit_date        label  F1  F2  F3  F4  F5       _label
0            1  2019-01-01        major   1   3   4   7   0        major
1            1  2019-04-05        patch   1   3   4   7   0        patch
2            1  2019-10-09            -   4   4   2   6   9        patch
3            2  2020-03-01  major.minor   1   9   4   5   5  major.minor
4            2  2020-03-05            -   3   6   2   1   8  major.minor
```

Comment: How so? The `df.join(_label).drop_duplicates(subset=subset)` generates your expected output, just drop the extra `_label` column created. The second half of the answer is about "counting the streaks" of change/non-change.

Comment: Okay. I've removed all that and just left the row removal part you explictly asked about. It removes the last row from your example data.

Comment: That suggests some other column in your data is not an exact duplicate, perhaps `groups[df.columns.difference(['label', 'commit_date'])].value_counts()` can help with debugging.

Comment: `(_label != _label.shift()).cumsum()` is one approach to grouping "consecutive values" together - the length of the group will be the count.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your problem a little bit. I hope I understood your problem correctly and this code helps you:

```
import pandas as pd

features = ["feature1", "feature2"]

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ["major", 1, 2],
    ["minor", 4, 2],
    ["minor", 3, 2],
    ["major", 1, 2],
], columns=["label"] + features)

labels = df.label.unique()

for label in labels:
    # filters df by label and then concatenates all feature columns to a tuple
    df_filtered = df[df.label == label].apply(lambda row: tuple([row[f] for f in features]), axis=1)
    print(df_filtered)

    # drop lines with identical features
    df_unique = df_filtered.drop_duplicates()
    print(f"{len(df_filtered) - len(df_unique)} values removed because of duplicates")

    # clean the original data frame
    df = df.drop(set(df_filtered.index) - set(df_unique.index))
```

Comment: I think it should be the other way around? IF there was a duplicate, then set label text to an empty string (instead of dropping it?

Comment: indeed, I dont get it. If you look at each `api_spec_id` independently, maybe make an example for a specific api id? It is also not clear to me how the date is important. If you make a copy paste python code for your input and expected output I'm more likely to grasp the problem and are happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

This answer addresses OP's updates

```
import pandas as pd

# name of features
features = ["F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5"]

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, "2019-01-01", "major", 1, 3, 4, 7, 0],
    [1, "2019-04-05", "patch", 1, 3, 4, 7, 0],
    [1, "2019-10-09", "-", 4, 4, 2, 6, 9],
    [2, "2020-03-01", "major.minor", 1, 9, 4, 5, 5],
    [2, "2020-03-05", "-", 3, 6, 2, 1, 8],
    [2, "2021-04-09", "-", 3, 6, 2, 1, 8],
], columns=["api_spec_id", "commit_date", "label"] + features)

api_spec_ids = df.api_spec_id.unique()

# perform action for each apic_spec_id seperately
for api_spec_id in api_spec_ids:
    # filter by spec id
    df_api_spec = df[df.api_spec_id == api_spec_id].copy()

    # sort by commit date
    df_api_spec.sort_values("commit_date", inplace=True)

    # iterate row ids, skipping first
    for idx in range(1, len(df_api_spec)):
        previous_row = df_api_spec.iloc[idx-1]
        row = df_api_spec.iloc[idx]

        # check if label and features stayed the same
        if (
            row.label == "-" and
            (row[features] == previous_row[features]).all()
        ):
            print("duplicate!")
            # drop the index of the duplicate entry from main DataFrame
            df.drop(df_api_spec.index[idx], inplace=True)

print(df)
```

output is

```
   api_spec_id commit_date        label  F1  F2  F3  F4  F5
0            1  2019-01-01        major   1   3   4   7   0
1            1  2019-04-05        patch   1   3   4   7   0
2            1  2019-10-09            -   4   4   2   6   9
3            2  2020-03-01  major.minor   1   9   4   5   5
4            2  2020-03-05            -   3   6   2   1   8
```

Comment: the final dataframe is df, not df_api_spec, there you should see that some rows are missing.