# Count similar instances based on condition for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
api_spec_id commit_date   label           F1       F2     F3     F4      F5
1           2019-01-01    major            1        3      4      7      0
1           2019-04-05    patch            1        3      4      7      0
1           2019-10-09                     4        4      2      6      9          
2           2020-03-01    major.minor      1        9      4      5      5
2           2020-03-05                     3        6      2      1      8
2           2021-04-01                     3        6      2      1      8
```

I want to count the number of instances where label remains the same and features change (F1,F2,F3,F4..and so on), and instances where label changes and features remain same. The empty rows indicate that the label doesn't change.

The expected output for the count would be something like this:

```
same_label_diff_features = 2 ( labels same, features change)
diff_label_same_features = 1 ( labels change, features same)
```

I tried using the below code to perform element wise comparison, but it doesn't seem to be the right approach.

```
same_label_diff_features = (pd.pivot_table(df_2015.iloc[:, 2:], index='_label', aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique)
                            .gt(1).sum(axis=0).sum())
```

Is there a better way to go about this? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Link to the previous question:[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75876294/compare-between-multiple-columns-and-remove-similar-instances).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.shift()` to compare against previous/next rows.

You can get the names of columns you want to compare:

```
>>> features = df.columns.difference(['api_spec_id', 'commit_date', 'label'])
>>> features
Index(['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5'], dtype='object')
```

Rows `1` and `5` have the same features as their previous row:

```
>>> df[features] == df[features].shift()
      F1     F2     F3     F4     F5
0  False  False  False  False  False
1   True   True   True   True   True
2  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False  False
5   True   True   True   True   True
```

`.all(axis=1)` can be added to get a single `True/False` answer per row.

It may also help to include a reference to the previous question as having the filled label column can be used here:

```
>>> _label
0          major
1          patch
2          patch
3    major.minor
4    major.minor
5    major.minor
Name: _label, dtype: object
```

Combining the comparisons for same labels, and different features:

```
>>> ((_label == _label.shift()) & (df[features] != df[features].shift()).all(axis=1))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
```

You can then `.sum()` the results.

```
>>> ((_label == _label.shift()) & (df[features] != df[features].shift()).all(axis=1)).sum()
2
>>> ((_label != _label.shift()) & (df[features] == df[features].shift()).all(axis=1)).sum()
1
```

You can also add an `api_spec_id` comparison, so you're only comparing rows within each "group" if needed.

Comment: I am getting a 0 output for both the cases, which is weird, the solution is perfectly correct, I don't know why the code keeps giving the wrong output.